# Keyboard typing delay in Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, keyboard

When I start typing (in a shell or in a browser) there's always a slight delay between the characters typed showing up. I had this problem in Ubuntu 19.10, switched to Kubuntu and it works flawlessly there. Now that I am back with Ubuntu 20.04, I have the same problem again.

Edit: I'm on a clean Ubuntu 20.04 install.

Comment: what shows `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard slowkeys-enable`

Comment: it shows false. I remember having checked these settings on my first 19.10 install but nothing worked.

Comment: Plese can you control `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard stickykeys-enable`

Comment: this one also shows up false

Comment: Then I have no other idea, sorry.

Comment: thank you :/ I'll probably go back to Kubuntu then...

Comment: I've found the answer to my specific instance of this keyboard delay problem.
Here is the [bug discussion](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1777708)
And the [particular solution I use](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/1858#note_818548) For reference, my keyboard is an old CM QuickFire TK.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there seems to be nothing in the Settings UI, but you may be able to change the settings with, e.g.:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard delay 250
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard repeat-interval 30
```